# Keep wordpress from modifying my permalinks

Tags: permalinks, slug

How can i stop wordpress from modifying my permalinks.

It is like it has a mind of its own. If I have title of the page such as: Top Benefits of Red Apples, the permalinks is top-benefits-apples.

When I try to change permalinks to yop-benefits-of-red-apples wordpress doesn't allow me to use this permalinks but it just goes back to the old one.

Such as on this site: http://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/wordpress-post-slug.png

I want the whole title to be included in the permalink.

Comment: There is a character limit of 200 imposed by the database structure: http://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP3.8-ERD.png (see the post_name column in the wp_posts table).  Are your permalinks over 200 characters in length?  The other possibility is that the slug (permalink) already exists in the database.

Comment: default WordPress doesn't alter permalinks that way, verify it's not a plugin or theme that is changing them.

Comment: You were right - this was the plugin called FV Simpler Seo that caused the problem. I disabled the option for shortening the permalinks in the plugin and now it works great.